# Get property values of properties of types derived from certain type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, reflection

I have an abstract class `Section` that will be used to represent a section of a document that can be either valid or invalid. Such sections can also have embedded sections. A section cannot be valid if it contains an invalid inner section.

I created classes `ASection1` and `ASection2` for the purpose of use them as inner sections of `MySection`, to which the validation process is invoked by means of `performValidation()`.

How do I get the properties of types derived from class MySection. I need help on the abstract class reflection logic as commented below.

```
 abstract class Section {

   constructor(public name: string) {
   }

   performValidation(): boolean {

       let result: boolean = true;

       //HELP IS NEEDED HERE!!!
       //get all properties of this instance 
       //whose type inherit from "Section"
       //and execute Validate() on each of them
       //one at a time, if any of them returns
       //false, return false.

       return this.Validate();
   }

   abstract Validate(): boolean; 
 }

 class ASection1 extends Section {
    constructor() {
       super("Section example 1"); 
    }
    Validate(): boolean {
       //validation logic goes here
    }
 }

 class ASection2 extends Section {
    constructor() {
       super("Section example 2"); 
    }
    Validate(): boolean {
       //validation logic goes here
    }
 }

class MySection extends Section {

   constructor() {
      super("My Section"); 
   }

   subsection1: ASection1;
   subsection2: ASection2;

   prop1: number;

   Validate(): boolean {
      return this.prop1 > 100;
   }

}

//run

let mySect = new MySection();
mySect.prop1 = 101;
mySect.subsection1 = new ASection1();
mySect.subsection2 = new ASection2();
mySect.performValidation();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just store sections in an array of a Map, rather than unknown individual properties?

Answer (score 0):

if you have 2 or more properties of the same type and same meaning **everytime** use array instead each property. I add subsections array to each subsection. In validation I check every subsection, if any subsection validation fail loop return false, if no subsection validation fails validation continues by validating itself.

```
abstract class Section {
    protected subsections: Array<Section> = [];

    constructor(public name: string) {
    }

    performValidation(): boolean {

        let result: boolean = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.subsections.length; i++) {
            if (!this.subsections[i].Validate()) {
                return;
            }
        }

        return this.Validate();
    }

    public addSubsection(section: Section) {
        this.subsections.push(section);
    }

    abstract Validate(): boolean; 
 }

 class ASection1 extends Section {
    constructor() {
       super("Section example 1"); 
     }

    Validate(): boolean {
        //validation logic goes here
    }
 }

 class ASection2 extends Section {
    constructor() {
       super("Section example 2"); 
    }
    Validate(): boolean {
        //validation logic goes here
    }
 }

class MySection extends Section {

   constructor() {
      super("My Section"); 
   }

   prop1: number;

   Validate(): boolean {
      return this.prop1 > 100;
   }

}

//run

let mySect = new MySection();
mySect.prop1 = 101;
mySect.addSubsection(new ASection1());
mySect.addSubsection(new ASection2());
mySect.performValidation();
```